# How to set blob properties and upload content as one request

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

When you have a `CloudBlockBlob blob`, you can upload some content, e.g.

```
blob.UploadText("content");
```

This would produce a http operation to get that done. But if I also want to set the content type, I also need

```
blob.Properties.ContentType = "text/plain";
blob.SetProperties();
```

Which produce another http operation to set that content type.

Even though azure pricing is very small per operation, in the long run this seems wasteful (and slow because of multiple roundtrips). Is there any way I can set the properties and content as one operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply setting the properties before calling `UploadText` will do the trick. So your code would be:

```
blob.Properties.ContentType = "text/plain";
blob.UploadText("content");
```

Comment: Thanks, I also attempted this by setting the properties then opening/writing/closing a CloudBlobStream and it seems to work